# Question about var_dump output

Tags: php, object, var-dump

When I `var_dump` an object, the output looks like this:

```
object(XCTemplate)#2477 (4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["db_table_name"]=>
  string(14) "template_names"
  ["cache"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

`XCTemplate` is its class, of course, but what does the integer (here: 2477) after the # mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a unique id associated with that particular instance of `XCTemplate`. AFAIK this is not documented, and also there is no way to get it (other than using `var_dump()`); and I've looked at the `Reflection` class.

From what I've seen:

- The ids are unique to every instantiation; starting at 1 and incrementing by 1 with every new object. This includes every object; they don't have to be of the same class.
- Destroying an instance (eg: through `unset`) frees up its id and the next instantiated object can (and will) use it.
- It's not related to the variable; eg:

  ```
  $foo = new Foo();
  var_dump($foo);
  $foo = new Foo();
  var_dump($foo);
  ```

  Will produce different id's for different instantiations.
- This is *not* the same as resource ids, where you can just convert to `int` to get the id:

  ```
  $resource= curl_init();      
  var_dump($resource);       // resource #1 of type curl
  print(intval($resource));  // 1
  print((int) $resource);    // 1
  ```

Comment: To add, on each instantiation, this number is incremented. If an instance is deleted (unset), that instance's # will then be reused on for the next instance.

Comment: Also, it's not an instance id of a particular class, but of any class.

Comment: Does this mean that 2477 objects have been initialized throughout the whole script? :O

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, that's what it looks like. Are you using a heavy framework?

Comment: I do, it heavily makes use of MVC. Still got a really snappy performance. Also, thanks a lot for your very detailed answer!